# Field of Fractions $F$ is a finitely generated $R$-module iff $F$ is equal to its integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Given $R$ an integral domain with field of fractions $F$, I want to prove $F$ is a finitely generated $R$-module if and only if $R = F$.

For $(\Rightarrow)$: I tried to first define a generating set based on the definition i.e. finitely many $m_1,\dots,m_n$ such that $\sum_i Rm_i  = M$. Then somehow show every element in $R$ is invertible. From where $D=F$ but how...

For $(\Leftarrow)$: If $R = F$, I am not sure, but I know by definition, the embedding of $R$ in $F$ maps each $n \in R$ to the fraction $\frac{an}{a}$ for nonzero $a$ in $R$. In further details, I am a bit lost though.

Answer (score 3):

If $F=R$, then you have nothing to prove.

Suppose $F$ is finitely generated as $R$-module. Let
$$
\left\{\frac{a_1}{c},\frac{a_2}{c},\dots,\frac{a_n}{c}\right\}
$$
be a set of generators. It's not restrictive to take the same denominator, because we can always multiply numerator and denominator by the same factor.

In particular, there are $b_1,\dots,b_n\in R$ with
$$
\frac{1}{c^2}=\frac{a_1}{c}b_1+\frac{a_2}{c}b_2+\dots+\frac{a_n}{c}b_n
$$
so
$$
\frac{1}{c}=a_1b_1+\dots+a_nb_n\in R
$$
Therefore…

Comment: Thank you! Is your c arbitrary in R such that we can thus conclude every element in R is invertible?

Comment: @Homaniac Not at all! We conclude *that* $c$ is invertible, so the generators of $F$ actually belong to $R$.

Comment: ooh so the argument that follows should be that c is thus invertible and we see the generators of F belong to R but I don't see why that leads to R= F.. :/

Comment: @Homaniac If the generators of $F$ belong to $R$, then every element of $F$ is in $R$ as well.

Comment: I must be missing something ridiculously simple here again but why is there 'nothing to prove' in the converse direction if R = F..?

Comment: @Homaniac $R$ is a finitely generated module over itself, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed, lastly I l wonder if we made use of the fact that R is an integral domain at any point or is that not necessary?

Comment: @Homaniac Well, if $R$ is not a domain, the field of fraction is not defined.

Comment: Thank you for the patient explanation, I posted another qns on algebraic integers if you're able to advice~